# Why there's a different answer for $\int x\ln{x^2}dx$ in wolfram alpha?

Tags: integration, wolfram-alpha

I'm attempting to solve $\int x\ln{x^2}dx$

Using integration by parts I was able to do the following steps.

$$2\int x \ln x dx=2\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\ln x -\int\frac{x^2}{2}dx\right)=x^2\ln x - \frac{x^3}{3}+c$$

But when I verified it with wolfram alpha, I'm getting a different answer.

i.e. $\frac{1}{2}x^2(\log x^2 -1)+c$

Can anyone please explain me why there's a difference? Thank you.

wolfram alpha link: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+xln%28x%5E2%29

Comment: yes. thanks for pointing that out. I've edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error; it should be
$$\int x\ln x^2 dx \overset{t=x^2}= \frac12\int \ln t dt= \frac12(t\ln t-t)+C$$

Comment: Can't I apply logarithm rule to it to take the power as a linear factor?

Comment: $\ln{x^r}=r\ln{x}$?

Comment: @emil - you could. Then, it should be $$2\int x\ln x dx = \int \ln x d(x^2) = x^2\ln x -\int xdx =x^2\ln x-\frac12 x^2$$

Comment: oh yes! I found my mistake. Thank you!!

Comment: @emil: You should mark this answer as accepted so that it doesn't queue in the Unanswered.

Comment: now its done :)